# How do I create a UX review for a website? Never done one before

Tags: usability, usability-testing, expert-review

Pls can I get a guidance as to how to create a UX review for a website? I'm a total noob on this. What do I look for?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice checklist to build off of here: https://www.process.st/checklist/ux-audit/

However, I'd also incorporate a couple very fast user walkthroughs if you can and/or expose and insights you can find based on analytics. UX audits are great, but their weakness can be putting too much weight on best practices without really knowing the personas and their pain points.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at the link. I've been looking around and there seems no standard practice. The ISO document looks too bulky as a help already